# Running External Application in a Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework Test

Tags: c++, .net, mfc

I am writing a test project for an MFC application using `Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework`, with a single step to verify end-to-end integration of the said application with all external parties (SQL Server and other entities). I need to start and control a number of external processes this MFC application will communicate with. One of these external applications uses dot NET framework v4.0.30319. When I try to start this utility using either `ShellExecute()` or `CreateProcess()`, it fails with the below message:

> Could not load file or assembly
> 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeCoverage.Shim, Version=15.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
> dependencies.

This is despite the fact that I can run the utility from command line directly, and can start other applications from the test project such as Windows Calculator or Notepad. To me, it seems like this dot NET application somehow detects the test environment, and wants to participate in it. If this is true, how can I prevent it? I just need to have this application (and quite a few more, all of which are dot NET applications) to run peacefully.